# Word VBA code for saving forms

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have Word survey files, each containing forms filled by subjects. Until now I have manually exported the forms data by saving as txt and choosing the option "save form data as delimited text file".

I want to programmatically save as delimited text file all the .doc documents in a given directory. Alternatively, if this were to be too complicated, it would be sufficient to save one file at a time. The new txt files must have the same name as the original .doc files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your input Jan Schejbal. I've reached a solution with this piece of code, so I share it for whose who encounter the same problem. I received help from [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=20)

```
Sub Save_Forms_Data()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document, strDocName As String
    strFolder = CurDir
    If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
    strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
    While strFile <> ""
        Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile,     AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
        With wdDoc
            strDocName = Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.FullName, ".")) & "txt"
            .SaveAs2 FileName:=strDocName, FileFormat:=wdFormatText,     AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
            SaveFormsData:=True, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False, LineEnding:=wdCRLF
            .Close SaveChanges:=False
        End With
        strFile = Dir()
    Wend
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Quit SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [record a macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/record-or-run-a-macro-HA010099769.aspx), which means you start the recording, do certain actions, then stop the recording, and VBA code for said actions is automatically generated. The code may not be very clean, but it should give you a good start to show you how the syntax looks and what commands you need for your actions. For certain things (e.g. dynamically specifying the file name), you will need to consult the documentation, but if you have any programming experience in any common language, this should not pose a significant problem once you have the "skeleton" provided by the macro recorder.

The more you want to automate, the more VBA you will need to learn. As VBA really isn't difficult, and it seems like you have a lot of repetitive work in front of you if you don't automate it, I'd suggest you learn it and Google what you need. This way, you will get your work done in a similar timeframe (or less, especially if this is not just a one-off thing), you will have a macro to do it next time, it will be less boring, and you will have learned a bit of VBA.